# Why permalink not working in mouseenter area

Tags: jquery

I create menu with `mouseenter` event to open it. But all permalink in `mouseenter` area can't click.

Here my code:

```
$( document ).on( 'mouseenter', 'li#"primary', function() {
    $( '.dropdown-menu' ).addClass( 'open' );
});

<ul>
    <li id="primary">
        <a href="#primary">Primary</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li> <-- this can't click
            .....
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's zero need to use javascript for this.  This can be done more reliably with CSS: `li:hover ul { display: block; }` - you can even add animations with CSS, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

The selector should `li#primary`

**cale_b:** since ID's need to be unique, better yet would be simply `#primary`

Comment: So, how to fix it. I want sub-menu keep open if mouse on sub-menu area.

Comment: Incorrect. Your selector has a space - there should be no space: `li#primary`, or since ID's need to be unique, better yet would be simply `#primary`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you keep the menu open when you go to click on the options. Your code doesn't show the mouseout event, but wherever it is, make sure it is for the element with id primary. Also, li elements are meant to be items in a list, and aren't very well suited for what you want to do. You should probably use the ul element to trigger the mouse events that way the entire element is used. Most likely once you move your mouse it moves off of the li element and hides the menu.